# script to clear note from unchecked checkbox

Tags: google-apps-script, checkbox, google-sheets, scripting

I'm not a programmer but like to play around with scripts every now and then as a hobby.

I built a spreadsheet to capture the timestamp in a 'note' every time a checkbox is checked, by piecing together code from various sources. However, I can't clear the note in the checkbox, when it is unchecked.

**CODE SAMPLE**

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if(e.value != "TRUE") return;
e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart,e.range.columnStart).setNote('Completed: ' + Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "dd-MM-yy HH:mm:ss"));
}
```

a side note: is this possible with comments instead of notes?

Comment: Hi, just wanted to check if the issue was still affecting you?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if(e.range.getSheet().getName()!='Sheet1')return;//Limits action to one sheet
  //e.source.toast('flag1');
  if(e.range.columnStart==1 && e.value == "TRUE") {//I have the checkboxes in columnA
    //e.source.toast('flag2');
    e.range.setNote('Completed: ' + Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "dd-MM-yy HH:mm:ss"));//sets note to completed
  }
  if(e.range.columnStart==1 && e.value == "FALSE") {
    //e.source.toast('flag3');
    e.range.setNote('');//Clears note
  }
}
```

In your case this is probably what you want.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if(e.value == "TRUE") {
    e.range.setNote('Completed: ' + Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "dd-MM-yy HH:mm:ss"));
  }
  if(e.value == "FALSE") {
    e.range.setNote('');
  }
}
```

Comment: unfortunately the scope is more global. I have multiple sheets and checkboxes are everywhere (not really structured)

Comment: Then look at my addition.

Comment: I already tried this but this doesn't delete the note. I also tried with 'clearNote'. also tried setnote ('')

Comment: It does for me. I added checkboxes to other sheets in many arbitrary locations.

Comment: when i say it doesn't work for me, I'm referring to specifically deleting the comment

Comment: I know.  It deletes the comment for me when I uncheck the checkbox.  Oh actually I've been using notes not comments.  Apps Script does deal with comments...only notes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if(e.value == "FALSE"){ 
    e.range.clearNote();
    return;
  }
  e.range.setNote('Completed: ' + Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "dd-MM-yy HH:mm:ss"));
}
```

Your code was right, you just needed to remove the note inside the `if` statement, I used `clearNote()` ([Documentation here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#clearnote)) to remove them if the values was `"FALSE"` The note itself might be still visible for a second after you uncheck the box, but it''l go away and it'll be removed from the cell.